# Calling a parents factory method during subclass instantation

Tags: python, oop

The problem in code:

```
class SuperObject:
    def __init__(self, property):
       self.property = preprocess(property)

    @classmethod
    def create (cls, property):
       super_object = cls.__new__(cls)
       # dont preprocess!
       super_object.property = property
       return super_object

class Object (SuperObject):
    def __init__(self, super_property, special_property):
        super().__init__(super_property)
        #problem: super_property gets preprocessed. How to use SuperObject.create here?
        self.special_property = special_property
```

As mentioned in the code, I dont want to call the constructor of SuperObject, instead I want to use the classmethod to create the parent. The example of course is a simplification of my use case so please excuse if in itselft it makes only limited sense.